# Signalr connecting to multiple Web applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, servicebus

We're planning on adding SignalR to several differnet web applications. The applications are targeted different aspects of an order. When something happens to an order, all users working with the order across all web applications should be notitfied.

Changes to an order are availible asa message on a servicebus.

We could implement the following logic in all web applications:

- Subscribe to a topic (one subscription per webapp)
- OnMessage -> Send orderId to hub
- Hub would notify clients working on the orderId

Question is: Could we implement all this common functionality in a separate application, and all web apps would reference the same signalr scripts?

All applications live on the same domain, and it would give us a lot of benefit not having to implement signalr in every app.

Good idea, or am I missing something important here?

**Edit:** Put in other words: I have WebAppA, WebAppB and WebAppC all without SignalR. I'm asking if its possible to create a WebappD that talks to clients in WebApp A,B,C

Comment: I don't think it is possible because every application have it's own Startup file and on Startup signalR establish a connection and provide a connection Id so how can we maintain. But it's a guess, appreciable if you can achieve this, I am also interested, if we can do this

Comment: I just did a small prototype, seems like it should work enabling CORS http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#crossdomain - Still interested in possible drawbacks with this approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second Solution is very good. it will move signalr load (espcially memory) from your main web apps to WebAppD(signalr web app). And all your main web apps will not be dependent to signalr.

*Drawbacks:* You don't have any authentication on WebAppD. Because clients are authenticated on the other WebApps. You should let the WebAppD knows about orderId. That's why, you should send message to server (WebAppD) from clients(Javascript).

Because of enable cross domain settings, anyone can send message to server. Even they don't need to be connected WebAppA,WebAppB or WebAppC. Even if you solve this problem (virtual path etc), Someone is connected but not authenticated  on WebAppA,WebAppB,WebAppC can sends message. Because WebAppD just get the message and it doesn't know this client is authenticated or not so it will serve this message to all others. In Short: Someone can send fake messages to other clients.

So you should share your authentication like [this](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/compatibility/cookie-sharing.html) (or some other logic) between your web app and signalr webapp.

Other than this I couldn't see any drawback.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I would avoid having SignalR hubs in WebApplications A,B, C (you say servers, A,B, C are actually WebApps, each running on loadbalanced servers) That is, WebApp D should use signalr to communicate with clients in WebApp A,B and C

Comment: Ok you are right I meant to be web apps. I thought differently. If web a,b,c clients are already connected D it's easier to manage. I will think about it and edit answer.